# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '-'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

```
 SqlCommand command1 = connection.CreateCommand();
 command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 command1.CommandText = "update product set product_qty=product_qty-"+t1.Text;
 command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In the shopping cart, when i enter "2" and click add to cart button, "product_qty" in the description should be updated to (OriginalQTY - 2 ). But i am getting this above error. Please help!

Comment: Check the double quotes after -

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Also note that SqlCommand is IDisposable so should be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use parameters. It makes the syntax clearer (and protect you from [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)).

Also try to use [[using]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) in order to [dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2) the objects.

```
// using usings :-)
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using (var command1 = connection.CreateCommand())
{
     command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

     // your query with parameter: @qty
     // note 
     command1.CommandText = "update product set product_qty -=@qty";

     // setting a type: aka VarChar, Int etc, will make sure you 
     // don't mix up all the ' and "'s
     command1.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Int);

     // set parameter value: all values are safe.
     // since you are using an int, make sure you put in an int.
     // [note] int.Parse("some text other than a number like 3") 
     // will throw an exception
     command1.Parameters["@qty"].Value = int.Parse(t1.Text);

     // execute
     command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Note: creating a param returns a ref to param so no need to deref twice: AND command1.CommandText = "update product set product_qty -=@qty"; parameter.value = .Value = t1.Text;

Comment: Firstly, Thanks a lot for your reply. However, i am still getting error
"Input string was not in a correct format"
also qty should be int, not var char (i change that already) :)

Comment: @WYMOWaiYan: Hi, I updated it a bit; it should work now. Although I didn't test it ;-)

Comment: @MitchWheat: thanks for the heads up. I think I finally understand what OP meant. XD

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for your kind reply. Sadly, the input was still not in a correct format :(

Comment: Can you show what you have got? Also the value of `t1.Text`. At this moment, for me this all is a bit "theoretic". A full example would help ;-)

Comment: By the way: probably your `t1.Text` value is not a number.

Comment: https://youtu.be/exH97SE7mFY. Check around 3min to this video @stefan. This is what I have been following and working on a project. I have been stuck here for quite some time. Will be such a marevlous help, if you can help me out :)

Comment: I followed excat same thing but I got error and I dunno where :( t1.text —> I input as 1 always

Comment: Some thing I need to know; 1) the exception, 2) the line number 3) the exact input of `ti.Text`, checked by your debugger. Do you know how to use the debugger? It's really helpful in these cases. You could also try to use `command1.Parameters["@qty"].Value = 3` just to make sure that piece works.

Comment: I didn’t debug properly because I get an error saying it’s a syntax error, so I was just focused on trying to fix the query command.   Now I carefully debug through again and I realsied I accidentally set the t1.text=“ “ ; now it’s fixed and all good. Thank you so much for your advises and help. God bless you! @stefan

Comment: @WYMOWaiYan Welcome to StackOverflow. The best way to thank Stefan is to take a moment to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).